# Why is this question considered to be about about general computing hardware and software?

Tags: discussion, scope

Question for reference: 
[Why is bash still searching for conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667818/why-is-bash-still-searching-for-conda)

This question was marked as off-topic with the reason

> "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming

I read the [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) site and the analogous one for [Super user](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).   I still don't see any reason why it is off-topic. Can someone please enlighten me.

Comment: That's a good question: Bash is a programming language; Python is a programming language; the question is about their interaction; and it has research, effort, and a well defined problem statement.  Conda is used by programmers. I'm not sure why it was closed.

Comment: Bash has over 100k questions.  It *seems* to be generally well accepted.

Comment: It was posted to SOCVR. Can't explain why it was closed though.

Comment: Because it's not about *programming* in bash, it's about a guessing game of "where on my disk is there something being run that's affecting my environment". If it is a programming problem, it lacks an actual MCVE, so there's no possibility of giving a definitive answer. The lack of a MCVE is evidenced by both answers just **guessing** at what the problem is, or just providing additional steps that can be taken to track down where the problem is.

Comment: @TejasShetty There is in essence nothing wrong with your question. You clearly did your research and try to address the problem yourself. From that perspective, your question is already better than a large fraction of the questions asked on this forum. Unfortunately, everything in your question points to a mild bug in a configuration file and is not really programming related. These questions are not really SO related. I would suggest to move it to [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: Also, to put a name on it. I suggested the close in the first place. But since I do not have a golden hammer, other users had to vote to close.

Comment: @kvantour NB - gold badge powers only work unilaterally for closing questions as duplicates, not for other close reasons.

Comment: Maybe it should be considered to change this quote.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That particular question has nothing to do with programming; not with bash programming; not with Python programming. You somehow have ended up with a misconfigured shell, which could and has happened before to many users and to many different programs.

The solutions to diagnose those problems are always the same, and so are the recipes to get them resolved. As such, it is a general computing problem, not a programming problem. That your issue involved two tools that happen to have tags here and are by themselves tools used in programming tasks don't make your specific issue on-topic for Stack Overflow. That is why it got closed as such.

Comment: @KevinB the main problem is that OP could also have misconfigured GIMP and Rythmbox, which would result in the same problem. So yes, the tools are used in programming, but what tool it was, is in this case not relevant to the problem.

Comment: How does one go about fixing a misconfigured bash shell?

Comment: @TejasShetty The best thing you can do is make a copy of your .bashrc and .bash_profile files and then clean them out. Restart bash reading the empty configuration files and see if you still have the problem. If the problem persists, bash is not the issue but something else. If the problem is gone, slowly feed in elements of the copied configuration files and restart the process until you find the line that creates the problem.

Comment: The way I have read the quote in OP's post above is that any question about tools used *primarily for programming* is OK (considering it doesn't run afoul of other off-topic rules). Bash is, AFAIK, used *primarily for programming* (AFAIK it actually is *only* used for programming) -- thus a question about a configuration error *in Bash* is OK here. Put another way, "How to configure a program" is off-topic here, *except when the program is one used primarily for programming*. I'm guessing you read that quote in OP's post a different way?

Comment: @TylerH yes, very much. Questions about how to set your environment vars or path in the Windows Command line are not on-topic either. At lest not to get your Eclipse IDE started.

Comment: @rene Gotcha; we simply disagree completely on this, then. IMHO how to change any setting or get any thing configured correctly in an IDE or programming tool/env is on-topic here, based on how I read the quote in the Help Center. (Though questions such as "what's the best configuration" or "do you prefer dark mode vs light mode", etc. would not be on-topic).

Comment: @TylerH well, yes. We disagree. If they had used the C Shell they would have ended up with the same problem. Their issue is more of a Shell configuration issue then anything else. IOW it is not Bash programming issue.  But let us disagree that is fine.

Comment: @TylerH As I'm sure you know, bash is a shell that's used to enter commands into various computers (a wide spectrum of machines; it's available on most machines in one way or another). While it is also used for programming, I'd say its primary use is general computer use and/or system administration. I have no statistics for that, but I wouldn't say that it's used primarily for actual programming. It *certainly* isn't *only* used for programming. My impression is that you may be conflating the computer use that you do day-to-day with the portion of what you do that is *actual* programming.

Comment: @Makyen I have never used bash. From what I know it's the same concept as running commands in PowerShell but from what you're saying it sounds like it's more for single *commands* a la the Command Prompt.